# SharePoint List form (add new items to the list)

Tags: list

**Basic Goal**

I am trying to create a new list form in SharePoint 2010 that contains a field that is bound to the list item's value. For example, what if I want a "phone number" field on my "new list item" form where the field displays the format (xxx)xxx-xxxx? How do I do that? Once the phone number is filled out and the new list item is created, the list itself should show the phone number (preferably with the formatting intact).

Please give me an idea of where to start. I started to create a new one in SharePoint Designer 2010, and I see the  tags that seem to represent the controls that are already bound to the new list item. So how do I bind my own control to the new list item? I don't care if this solution uses SharePoint Designer 2010 or Visual Studio 2010. I'm only looking for some idea of where to start... I don't understand how the list form is tied to the list.

I see that SPD 2010 has validation capabilities, but at some point in my project, I will need formatting AND validation.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I flagged your question to have it moved to SharePoint StackExchange. Hopefully you'll get more advice there.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's an application for building advanced forms for SharePoint, called InfoPath. This might be your best bet, considering your requirements.

Without InfoPath, I would use a standard SharePoint form, and add some JavaScript or jQuery for validation and formatting on the fly. Plugins like jQuery Validate might work for you.

You could use SharePoint Designer to bind fields to a list, but it seems to be too much trouble compared to the above options.

Comment: How can I use SPD to bind fields to a list? Everything I've seen thus far starts out with fields already bound to the list. Additionally, what happens if I want the new list item form to say (xxx)xxx-xxxx but the list to say the full string of numbers xxxxxxxxxx without the formatting. What happens if I also want the list to have the formatting? These are the kind of questions I'm looking for answers to. That being said, JQuery doesn't seem like a bad idea, nor do your other suggestions.

Comment: That's what you should do, use a field already bound to the list. If not, you'll need to write your own code to write back to the list, using Web services for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, in a forum it is hard to answer such open questions. All of what you want is possible. If you need flexibility, client side code (JavaScript/jQuery) is your best bet. It will allow you to disconnect the data from the rendering.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't answer my original question. I want to use List forms because that is the standard SharePoint\ way of customizing the interface that allows the user to create, read, or update list items. even if you can point me in the right direction that would be helpful...